# SUM of TIMEDIFF while comparing two different date ranges

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, sum, mariadb

I have two SQL tables. One contains job names. In a second table I have datetime entries (in and out) that are tagged to a job.

Jobs Table

```
jobId,  jobName
1       MyJob
2       AnotherJob
3       ThisJob
```

Timers Table

```
timerId,  timerIn,              timerOut,             jobs_jobId
1         2020-07-30 16:03:00   2020-07-30 16:17:11   1
2         2020-07-30 14:00:00   2020-07-30 15:00:00   3
3         2020-06-30 16:17:12   2020-07-30 16:49:52   1
4         2020-07-30 16:20:00   2020-07-30 16:38:00   2
5         2020-06-24 08:44:00   2020-07-24 11:18:00   3
6         2020-06-30 15:35:00   2020-07-30 16:02:00   1
```

My current query works flawlessly for summing the total hours per job for the current month.

```
SELECT 
    `jobName`,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`timerOut`, `timerIn`)) / 3600) AS `thismonthHours`
FROM
    `timers`
        INNER JOIN
    `jobs` ON `jobs`.`jobId` = `timers`.`jobs_jobId`
WHERE
    `timerIn` >= '2020-07-01 00:00:00'
        AND `timerOut` <= '2020-07-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY `jobName`
```

Outputs (based on larger sample then shown above)

```
jobName,    thismonthHours
MyJob       81.3484
AnotherJob  9.6500
ThisJob     4.9500
```

I'm looking for a way to output the sum of hours for both this month and the previous month in a single query, output should look something like this

```
jobName,    thismonthHours, lastmonthHours
MyJob       81.3484         54.8150
AnotherJob  9.6500          68.1425
ThisJob     4.9500          1.2412
```

Comment: I would start from the `jobs` table, and then `LEFT JOIN` two subqueries, both on `timers`, one per month, selecting the `SUM(...)` for each job id (`GROUP BY`) in that month. Finally, in your main query you can check for `NULL` values in your sums, in case you don't want to display jobs that weren't run at all

Answer (score 0):

It is more complicated that you might think. You need to take the possibility that a job execution would span over two different months, in which case we need to break down the execution time.

Here is on approach using a left join, then `least()` and `greatest()`. It computes the current month dynamically so you don't need to rewrite the query when the month changes:

```
select 
    j.jobName,
    sum(case when t.timerOut  >= d.dt
        then unix_timestamp(least(t.timerOut, d.dt + interval 1 month)) - unix_timestamp(greatest(t.timerIn, d.dt))
        else 0
    end) / 3600 hours_this_month,
    sum(case when t.timerIn  < d.dt
        then unix_timestamp(least(t.timerOut, d.dt)) - unix_timestamp(greatest(t.timerIn, d.dt - interval 1 month))
        else 0
    end) / 3600 hours_last_month
from (select date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') dt) d
cross join jobs j
left join timers t
    on  j.jobId = t.jobs_jobId
    and t.timerIn  <  d.dt + interval 1 month
    and t.timerOut >= d.dt - interval 1 month
group by j.jobId, j.jobname
order by j.jobId
```

You did not show the result that you expect for your actual sample data. [In this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09e19739acdfb0e2c5210acad5eba769), this produces:

```
jobName    | hours_this_month | hours_last_month
:--------- | ---------------: | ---------------:
MyJob      |  1425.1008333333 |    16.1300000000
AnotherJob |     0.3000000000 |     0.0000000000
ThisJob    |   564.3000000000 |   159.2666666667
```